# Unable to send email using core php

Tags: php, email

I'am newbie in php. I'am trying to send email using php but I don't know what's wrong in my code. I googled a lot but nothing has worked yet. Here is my php code. I'am using class.phpmailer.php.

```
<?php

require("phpmailer-master/class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP(); // send via SMTP
IsSMTP(); // send via SMTP
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // turn on SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = "myemail@googlemail.com"; // SMTP username
$mail->Password = "mypassword"; // SMTP password
$webmaster_email = "recipient@googlemail.com"; //Reply to this email ID
$email="username@domain.com"; // Recipients email ID
$name="myname"; // Recipient's name
$mail->From = $webmaster_email;
$mail->FromName = "Webmaster";
$mail->AddAddress($email,$name);
$mail->AddReplyTo($webmaster_email,"Webmaster");
$mail->WordWrap = 50; // set word wrap
$mail->AddAttachment("/var/tmp/file.tar.gz"); // attachment
$mail->AddAttachment("/tmp/image.jpg", "new.jpg"); // attachment
$mail->IsHTML(true); // send as HTML
$mail->Subject = "This is the subject";
$mail->Body = "Hi,
This is the HTML BODY "; //HTML Body
$mail->AltBody = "This is the body when user views in plain text format"; //Text Body
if(!$mail->Send())
{
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
else
{
echo "Message has been sent";
}
?>
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
else
{
echo "Message has been sent";
}
?>
```

Comment: what error you are getting @Pooja?

Comment: Nothing. Just a blank page and I've even seen the console.

Comment: Is the code above correct or are the last few lines duplicated when you cut and paste. Also line 6 IsSMTP(); // send via SMTP, should be removed

Comment: @pooja are you trying to send it through `localhost` or a `live server` if you are in `localhost` than try using live server. may be `php mailer` isnt been configured from your `php.ini`

Comment: Yes i am trying to send at localhost

Comment: @NishantSolanki please provide me link where i will get working email sending php program\

Comment: @bumperbox sir i am using code from this site please see http://deepakssn.blogspot.in/2006/06/gmail-php-send-email-using-php-with.html

Comment: what do you mean by live server? and i have apache server sir

Comment: Try to set error reporting in php.ini to E_ALL, that will show you the error you get.

Comment: please somebody provide me working code for core php, I am running that in apache server, i have PHP 5.4.31. I am new in php so not getting the modifications you are telling. If you have any link for sending email using php then provide me. thanks

Comment: @NishantSolanki So you mean the mail can only be sent when it is hosted???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could finally send a mail using php. Here is the code:

```
<?php

require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
include("class.smtp.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->CharSet="UTF-8";
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->Username = 'sender@mail.com';
$mail->Password = 'sender_password';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

$mail->From = 'sender@mail.com';
$mail->FromName = 'sender';
$mail->AddAddress("sender@mail.com");
$mail->AddReplyTo("sender@mail.com", 'Information');

$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Subject    = "Sample exmple to check proper working of mail function";
$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!";
$mail->Body    = "Hello ";
$path = $_POST['upload'];
$mail->AddAttachment($path); // attachment
if(!$mail->Send())
{
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
else
{
  echo "Message sent!";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP(); // send via SMTP

// Comment out this line here it is wrong
// IsSMTP(); // send via SMTP

$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // turn on SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = "username@gmail.com"; // SMTP username
$mail->Password = "password"; // SMTP password
$webmaster_email = "username@doamin.com"; //Reply to this email ID
$email = "username@domain.com"; // Recipients email ID
$name = "name"; // Recipient's name
$mail->From = $webmaster_email;
$mail->FromName = "Webmaster";
$mail->AddAddress($email, $name);
$mail->AddReplyTo($webmaster_email, "Webmaster");
$mail->WordWrap = 50; // set word wrap


// i would also comment out these lines, get it working without attachments first
// then add then back in after (if you want attachments)
// $mail->AddAttachment("/var/tmp/file.tar.gz"); // attachment
// $mail->AddAttachment("/tmp/image.jpg", "new.jpg"); // attachment


$mail->IsHTML(true); // send as HTML
$mail->Subject = "This is the subject";
$mail->Body = "Hi,
This is the HTML BODY "; //HTML Body
$mail->AltBody = "This is the body when user views in plain text format"; //Text Body
if (!$mail->Send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message has been sent";
}

// at the end of the pasted code above, you have these lines (below here) doubled up.
// remove them

echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
else
{
echo "Message has been sent";
}
?>
```

Comment: What all should be filled in the fields below?
$mail->Username = "username@gmail.com"; // SMTP username
$mail->Password = "password"; // SMTP password
$webmaster_email = "username@doamin.com"; //Reply to this email ID
$email = "username@domain.com"; // Recipients email ID

Means where should I specify Sender's username & Recipient's username? It has been a bit confusing for me sir.

Comment: they should be set to the username and password for your email server.

Comment: Sir what do you mean by email server?